# How do I get the original value of a JTable cell in a TableModelEvent?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Let's say I change a cell with value "old" to "new". This will invoke tableChanged(TableModelEvent). How do I retrieve the value that the cell had before "new"(which should be "old")?

I thought about making a copy of TableModel of my JTable,but is there a simpler and smarter way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the time `tableChanged` has being fired, it's to late, the value has changed. About the only place you can catch this is in the `setValue` method of the table model.  I'd simply have a map in the model keyed to the column name that maintains a pair of objects, the old and new value, which you can look up

Comment: Also see [JTable: Detect cell data change](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6889694/1048330).

Comment: Why and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this when your table loads first time 
int row1=table.getRowCount();
        int column=table.getColumnCount();
        val=new Object[row1];
        val1=new Object[row1];
        for(int j=0;j<row1;j++){
            val[j]=table.getValueAt(j, 0);
            val1[j]=table.getValueAt(j, 1);

        }
```